# nested for loop breaks parent loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

```
function next() {
        document.getElementById('config').setAttribute("hidden","true");
        document.getElementById('formdiv').removeAttribute("hidden");
        mixer();
}
function mixer() {
    var x = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < parseInt(document.getElementById('nm').value); i++) {
        var title = document.createElement("P");
        title.style = "font-family:verdana;font-size:18px;";
        title.id = "p"+String(i);
        document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(title);
        document.getElementById("p"+String(i)).innerText = "Enter the amount of mixer number "+String(i+1);

        var mixers = document.createElement("INPUT");
        mixers.type = "text";
        mixers.id = "m"+String(i);
        mixers.size = '1';
        document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(mixers);

        var options = ['Select a unit','ml','L','UK Pints','US Pints'];

        var dropdown = document.createElement("SELECT");
        dropdown.id = "s"+String(x);
        document.getElementById("myForm").appendChild(dropdown);

        /*for (j = 0; i < options.length; j++) {
            var optiontag = document.createElement("OPTION");
            optiontag.value = options[j];
            optiontag.innerText = options[j];
            document.getElementById("s"+String(x)).appendChild(optiontag);
        }*/
        x += 1;
    }
}
```

this function creates the output when passed mn = 3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pgzR.jpg

when i un-comment the nested loop at the bottom, it outputs this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ck9B.jpg

it should output the same as the first image but with the options for the 
dropdown menus

Comment: `i < options.length` should be `j < options.length`

Comment: Note you don't need the `<select>` id to append the options since you already have a reference to the element as `dropdown`. Can simplify to `dropdown.appendChild(optiontag)`

Comment: `"m"+String(i)` why the `String`... Back to JS basics

Comment: Also `document.getElementById` and in general, querying the DOM inside a loop is such a bad idea. Cache your selectors into variables beforehand.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Why is it a bad idea, and what do you mean by caching them? like setting `nm = document.getElementById('nm')` etc

Comment: @JackRycroft exactly, you got that perfectly right! That variable will be like a cached "pointer" to the DOM Element. Otherwise you're forcing the parser to scrape all over again the entire DOM in search for that element.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan so will this make it load faster and be more efficient?

Comment: @JackRycroft not only load faster, but will keep other resources free for other processes. Querying for IDs is fast, but learn it the right way - straight-away, since one day those might be classes selectors or attribute selectors which will result in much, much worse performance.

Comment: Also, create a function that returns your new elements (like select, input etc). So basically all you need inside that `for` loop should be a single function like `createFormElements(i)` - even better performance :). It's like, say you have N people working for your company, assigning instructions inside a for loop is like calling each person individually explaining their tasks all over again. Store into a function and it's like calling them all together for a training meeting :)